# One way function to hash a variable length string into a 12 digit number in Groovy

Tags: java, random, groovy, hash

I have list of unique variable length strings composed of letters, numbers and special characters(email addresses).  Each email address in the list is unique.

I need a one way hash function(I do not need to be able to retrieve the original value from the generated number) that will hash the string with a salt and generate a 12 digit number.

I want to ensure uniqueness so I will check the list of previously generated values to detect collisions and then generate a new number if there is a collision.  Predictability is not an issue.

Ideally I would like this function to be written in Groovy, but Java would also be fine.

Comment: You are looking for a [perfect hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash), which always exists so long as there are fewer input strings than possible output strings (10^12 in your case).  However, the resulting hash function is specific to that particular data-set; you can't use it on a different data-set and still guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: I have changed the requirement that generated values do not have to be guaranteed to be unique.  I will check for collisions in generated values by checking the list of already created values.  Is there anything else I need to correct in my request?

Comment: Or can I just append a portion of the original input(the email) to the generated id to make it unique?

Comment: @anataliocs The problem with checking for collisions is that at that point it is too late to do anything without throwing out the hash and starting over, and it requires recording the original values (barring additional input restrictions). It can tell there *is* a problem, but likely isn't what is required.. what is the *end purpose* of such a mapping? Hashing is great because it is repeatable given only the input. However, if such a mapping is maintained in a database (the "output" needs not be [entirely] dependent upon the input), then that is an entirely different ballgame...

Comment: Of course, 12 [hex] digits is still a "pretty darn big value" so, given a "relatively small number" of inputs, there is a *very good chance* that a well-distributed hash (say, the top 12 digits of a SHA1) will yield a unique mapping. The *guarantee* that this is so is not there, however. Increasing the target space greatly reduces the likelihood of such a [random] collision. Compare the "short node ID" (12 hex digits = 60 bits, very low chance of collision) and "node ID" (160 bits, assumed to be unique and would kill an Hg repo if not) used in Mercucial/Hg (and Git).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to guarantee that each generated number will be unique.

Well that's clearly going to be a problem. There are more possible input strings than possible output values. In particular, every possible output value (a 12-digit string) is a possible input value. Therefore if all of those get unique output values, there can't possibly be any output values left for any *other* input values.

Of course you could always *record* each email address you encounter (so the first one ends up with 000000000000, the second gets 000000000001 etc) but that's a storage matter rather than hashing as such. You can't get to the output from *just* the input, without the backing store.

Comment: There would be conflict problem for the outputs.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: Exactly - you *can't* generate unique numbers when there are more possible inputs than outputs.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If you know the list beforehand, yes. If the function has to just accept a string, with no other reference data or storage, you're in trouble...